# Google ima3.js via require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, google-ima

how can I include Google  library [ima3.js](https://s0.2mdn.net/instream/html5/ima3.js) to my module using `require.js`?

I'm trying like this, but unsuccesfully:

```
define(['uiBase', 'base', 'const', 'https://s0.2mdn.net/instream/html5/ima3.js'], function (UIBase, Base, Const, AdSDK) {
function Ad (params) {
    var params = params || {};

    /*-- Section to build ui elements --*/
      var adsLoader = new AdSDK.google.ima.AdsLoader(adDisplayContainer);
    /*-- End of section --*/
    };
return Ad;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. If it will be usefull to someone: All this code are work correcly, just to call ima functions I need to call them as:

```
var adsLoader = new google.ima.AdsLoader(adDisplayContainer);
```